# Changing kivy widget properties within Class

Tags: python, properties, widget, kivy, getattr

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to change the text of a label within a kivy widget. For simplicity, I have a label set to 0 and I would like to change the text to read 30 in this example. However, I get the following error.

AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '**getattr**'

I understand that I'm probably not properly targeting that widget and I am hoping someone can please explain how to specifically reference the text of this label (self.ids.mainel1temp.stuff_r.text = '30') to update (with more detail than fixing the code)

```
#!/usr/bin/kivy
import kivy


from random import random
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.switch import Switch
from kivy.uix.label import Label

from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '800')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '480')

Builder.load_string("""

<Menuscreen>:
    #Handling the gesture event.
    ScreenManager:
        id: manager
        Screen:
            id: main_screen
            name:'main_screen'
            stuff_r: mainel1temp
            FloatLayout:

                Label:
                    id: mainel1temp
                    size: self.texture_size
                    text:'0'
                    size_hint: None, None
                    text_size: 75,75
                    pos: 295,308
                    font_size:'20sp'
                    halign: 'center'



""")

class Thermostuff(Screen):
    stuff_r = ObjectProperty(None)

    def starttherm(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval((self.read_temp), 1)

    def read_temp(self, dt):
        self.ids.mainel1temp.stuff_r.text = '30'


Thermrun = Thermostuff()
Thermrun.starttherm()

class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass

sm = ScreenManager()
menu_screen = MenuScreen(name='menu')
sm.add_widget(menu_screen)


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):

        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

You do a couple of things wrong here.
You dont want to put a `ScreenManager` inside a `Screen`
Only one `ScreenManager` is needed.
Then you can start the `Clock` in the `__init__` of the `Thermostuff(Screen)`
Or if you want it to initiate `on_enter` you need to overrite that. In that case you might want to check somehow, if its allready started, so you wont have multiple clocks running.
Then when you create an `ObjectProperty` you dont need `self.ids`, because you allready created that property. So `self.stuff_r` is now the label.

I rewrote your example a bit, to demonstrate this.
Try this:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock

sm = """


#Handling the gesture event.
ScreenManager:
    id: manager
    MenuScreen:
        Button:
            text: "Go to Thermostuff"
            on_release:
                root.current = "main_screen"
    Thermostuff:
        name:'main_screen'
        stuff_r: mainel1temp
        FloatLayout:

            Label:
                id: mainel1temp
                size: self.texture_size
                text:'0'
                size_hint: None, None
                text_size: 75,75
                pos: 295,308
                font_size:'20sp'
                halign: 'center'



"""

class Thermostuff(Screen):
    stuff_r = ObjectProperty(None)
    test_temp = 0

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Thermostuff,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval((self.read_temp), 1)

    def read_temp(self, dt):
        self.test_temp += 1
        self.stuff_r.text = str(self.test_temp)


class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):

        return Builder.load_string(sm)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```